# Express Nearest Neighbor Join in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables Q and T, both containing a column of float numbers.

What I want to do is, for each number in Q, I want to find a number in T that has the smallest distance to it.

For example, for T={1,7,9} and Q={2,6,10}, I want to return Q,T pairs as {(2,1),(6,7),(10,9)}.

How should I express this query with SQL?

In addition, is that possible to accelerate this join by index, e.g. add an operator class which bind "FOR ORDER BY <->" with fabs calculation?

Comment: What would you expect as output if the values were 1,7,9 and 2,8,10 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
create table t (val_t integer);
create table q (val_q integer);

insert into t values (1),(7),(9);
insert into q values (2),(6),(10);
```

Start with a query that cross joins the two tables and adds a rank based on the difference:

```
SELECT val_q, val_t, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY val_q ORDER BY abs(val_t - val_q))
FROM t
JOIN q ON true ;
```

Use this query in a cte or subquery and filter by rank:

```
WITH src AS(
SELECT val_q, val_t, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY val_q ORDER BY abs(val_t - val_q))
FROM t
JOIN q ON true )
SELECT  val_q, val_t FROM src
WHERE rank = 1;


 val_q | val_t 
-------+-------
     2 |     1
     6 |     7
    10 |     9
```

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/tutorial-window.html

Answer (score 0):

Given this schema:

```
create table t (tn float);
insert into t values (1), (7), (9);

create table q (qn float);
insert into q values (2), (6), (10);
```

`DISTINCT ON` is the most straightforward way:

```
select distinct on (qn) qn, tn
  from q
       cross join t
 order by qn, abs(qn - tn);
```

Exploiting a numeric range may perform better depending on your data sizes.  If performance is an issue, then you can create an actual temp table for the `range_tn` CTE and put a gist index on it:

```
with all_tn as (
  select tn
    from t
   union select null
), range_tn as (
  select numrange(tn::numeric, (lead(tn) over w)::numeric, '[]') as tr
    from all_tn
  window w as (order by tn nulls first)
)
select qn,
       case 
         when lower_inf(tr) then upper(tr)
         when upper_inf(tr) then lower(tr)
         when 2 * qn - lower(tr) - upper(tr) > 0 then upper(tr)
         else lower(tr)
       end as tn
  from q
       join range_tn
         on qn::numeric <@ tr;
```

[Fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c869cc0cd0810f8f74b1e7243c3f92b8)